# How to Prefix an angular value in html?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-ui

How to prefix an angular value in HTML side.

In my project i am using the below line to show zip code .

```
<span>{{activeProperty.Zip}}</span>
```

I want that while displaying the zip, it will check whether the `activeProperty.Zip` length is 5 or not.if it is less then five then add leading zeros to `activeProperty.Zip`

For example if 4567 then it will show 04567 but if 45670 is there then will show 46670 only.

I dont want to do this in angular side as updating the `activeProperty.Zip` in controller leads so many issue as using the same in so many places. Is their any way to do it in HTML side ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create a filter that will pad the zip with zeroes, see this fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/11739/

```
myApp.filter('pad', function () {
    return function(zip) {
        var newZip = zip;
        if (zip.length < 5) {
            newZip = Array(6 - zip.length).join('0') + newZip;
        }
        return newZip;
    };
});
```

in your html: `{{activeProperty.Zip | pad}}`

Answer (score 0):

You can still do it angular side without changing model with use of filters, here is simple example that you can extend for your use

```
app.filter('prefixMe', function() {
  return function(input) {
    return input.length < 5 ? '0' + input : input
  };
});

<span>{{activeProperty.Zip | prefixMe}}</span>
```